# how to implement search and sorting function in Django table

Tags: python, django, search, django-tables2, django-filters

I know that there are Django-datatable, django_tables2, and even django_filter to perform search and sorting to the table.  I have tried using Django-datatable, django_tables2 and even django_filter, but none of them work. I have attached my code for the template. I am rendering two different tables using the code below, one is with action and status column while the other is without these two columns.

```
{% if some %}
    <table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Student ID </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Student Name </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Start Date </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > End Date </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Action </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Status </th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in query_results %}
            <tr align="center">
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.studentID}} </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.studentName}} </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.startDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.endDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" >
                    {% if item.status == 'Approved' %}

                    {% else %} 
                        <a href="{% url 'timesheet:edit' id=item.id status='a' %}"><button onclick="alert('timesheet accepted')">Approve</button></a> <a href="{% url 'timesheet:edit' id=item.id status='d' %}"><button onclick="alert('timesheet denied')")>Deny</button></a>
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > 
                    {% if item.status %}
                    {{item.status}}
                    {% else %}
                        Pending
                    {% endif %}       
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% else %}
    <table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Student ID </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Student Name </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > Start Date </th>
            <th style="font-family: Calibri" > End Date </th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in query_results %}
            <tr align="center">
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.studentID}} </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.studentName}} </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.startDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
                <td style="font-family: Calibri" > {{item.endDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

This is the search bar that i am after.
[Search bar to find by studentID,studentName,startDate,endDate,status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVjeF.png)

**LATEST : EDITED CODE USING [THIS LINK](https://djangobook.com/django-forms/) TO IMPLEMENT SEARCH BAR**

i follow the tutorial in this link, but when i enter the studentID in the search bar, all of the data being displayed but not the particular entered data.

***template .html file***

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <button type="submit" style="float: right;"> Search </button>
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" style="float: right;">
</form>
<br></br>

{% if timesheets %}               
     {% for timesheet in timesheets %}               
        <li>{{ timesheet.studentID }} - {{ timesheet.studentName }} - {{ timesheet.startDate }} - {{ timesheet.endDate }} - {{ timesheet.status }} </li>           
     {% endfor %} 
{% else %}
    //display all the data
{% endif %}
```

***views.py***

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        timesheets = Timesheet.objects.filter(studentID__icontains=q)
        return render(request, 'timesheet/supervisor_list_timesheet.html',
                  {'timesheets': timesheets})
```

Comment: What's not easy about django-tables2 + django-filter? Have you seen http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/filtering.html

Comment: @Jieter thanks for the link. I'll have a look at those.

Comment: @Jieter i have tried using fjango-filter as the updated code in my post, but the search is not working still. May i know where did i do wrong ?

Comment: Please have a careful look at the example in the docs. Also, you could try playing with the example project in https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/tree/master/example, it also has a [filtered view](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/612dd7f24ab9fe681340b6e015396afde38ad09f/example/app/views.py#L139-L144).

Comment: @Jieter I have looked through the link that you provided and tried those out, but all i got is a table. I am finding solution to do the search bar for the table that i just included the image in my question

Comment: (please try to use the class based view from the example first, and if you managed to get that to work, try to transfer things over to your preferred workflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the table displays some data correctly, you must also make sure the filter formset is displayed. I usually use something like this (in this case using `{% load bootstrap3 %}`

```
{% if filter %}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
            {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
            {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
        </form>
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

In case the filterset is assigned to the template context as `filter`, which should be the case [when using the example from django-tables2 filtering page](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/filtering.html)